What do rich people do differently with their bodies in the future?
To take a drastic oversimplification that is not reflective of many individuals opinions or of entire regions/cultures/subcultures throughout history, standards of attractiveness have evolved with our level of technology and nutritional access.  For the sake of this question, take as a constraint that we can examine the historical zeitgeist directly and in doing so have concluded that societal standards of attractiveness can be explained purely through the economic lens of the thing that is scarce being the thing that is desirable.  (Note: I am not saying this is actually the way the world works; it is just the particular aspect of the world I would like to focus on in this question.)
For example, by some measures, the "ideal" female form has changed over several hundred years to go from full-bodied to skinny to athletic (reference).  Male bodies have undergone a similar arc (reference).  Pre-industrialization, when nutrition was scarce, being fat was a sign of wealth.  Once calories became plentiful in developed countries, good nutrition remained scarce so being skinny is a sign of being rich.  As we move to modern times, good nutrition becomes cheaper, but the leisure time and spare money to go to the gym remain scarce, so having a toned body is a sign of being rich.
Let's fast forward a couple hundred years into the future.  People have easy access to calories and nutrition, as well as medication to control weight and prompt healthy muscle growth.  What body attribute remains a bastion of the rich and has become the new thing that the lower classes aspire to have?  To put that another way, what thing is something people would want to do to their bodies for aesthetic appeal that would remain expensive despite several hundred years of technology development?

Please note that the "ideal" female form depends very heavily on local culture, and it may differ again from what men actually find attractive. And also please note that the "ideal" male form has always been "rich" and still is; as the saying goes, from a purely physical point of view all a man needs is to be just a little more handsome than the devil.

@AlexP I started this question off with a big caveat saying most of that

I'm finding it tough to see how this isn't opinion-based. You've told us it's at least part cultural, but not told us anything about your future culture. Could you add lots of those details.

@Escapeddentalpatient. I'm trying to ignore the cultural component and focus solely on the technology/economic piece to keep this not opinion-based.  (I've removed the "culture" tag)

Rich is a word that just means someone with money. You can literally look around you to see how people with money act differently depending on their character and morals.
This is 100% opinion bases. As opposed to if you asked what would soldiers, tennis players, people in cold climates...etc do with access to X tech in this situation. Because you have a limited field and limited desired outcome. Fight better, play better tennis, survive the cold better..etc. But rich does not cover this in any way. Rich basically has no constraints and is too broad and vague. Needs to be changed.

It's all going to be about nostril size, the bigger the better.

I’m voting to close this question because (a) it's opinion-based (all answers have equal value VTC:NAWPH) and is too dependent on both the story (VTC:TSB) and on the choices of individuals and organizations (VTC:NAWPH). This is an off-topic infinite list of things question as quite literally anything can catch the fancy of the wealthy and prognosticating 100 years into the future is impossible without knowing the OP's whole story.

BTW, I'm having trouble reconsiling your question (What body attribute remains a bastion of the rich and has become the new thing that the lower classes aspire to have?) with the [tag:technological-development] tag (For questions about the progress of a society's technological state).

Upgrades.
The rich can not only do what the "normals" do, keep their body at the peak of normal human fitness, they can upgrade and augment their bodies.

Human lifespan. This could be increased by N or 2*N fold perhaps, not just total length of life, but healthy, active and fit life. Immortality might be an aspiration, but work is ongoing.

Athletic enhancement. This would extend to endurance, explosive strength and  such things as coordination and balance. Any rich person might be able to engage in gymnastic displays, but with the (false) modesty of cultural elitism come a reluctance to engage in casual displays of prowess (unless in competition for a mate/business etc.). I suppose some sort of sexual enhancement might fit in this category, but the exact nature of this I leave to the writer.

Superbrain. Imagine a lawyer that holds the entire case-law for every jurisdiction on the planet, the transcripts, the laws and byelaws, plus the unspoken customs of every neighborhood everywhere - all in memory (at a cost). Every argument ever made can be brought instantly to mind, cued-up by the intracranial AI-implant for salience and persuasive power in front of a jury. Medical/mathematical/historical etc. upgrades can be available for a price.

Sensory enhancement. Vision and hearing seem the obvious ones, but touch and smell might be useful for those intimate encounters. For more social-use, hearing someone's heartrate and smelling their current fear levels might be essential tools for running a household or business. For polite society, it might be considered impolite or downright rude to be seen to have them switched-on - an invasion of privacy.

Tools. This may seem an odd one, but think of Fabergé. The most famous fine-artist might equip his hands with all the tools of his remarkably lucrative trade. How do you think the Banksys of the future can remain able to move around without all the paint-cans getting noticed. This goes for the top thieves, safe-crackers etc.. This would also extend to implants being good for the tools of business - being able to make financial decisions, conduct transactions etc..

Identity changing. The ability to change one's face and appearance at will would be a must for young socialites who might like to disassociate themselves from their more exuberant public mistakes. This might include pheromone-generating abilities. This might even extend to repeated sex-change. The extreme explorers of this tech could experience species-change for a sabbatical. Banksy likes this one.

Communication and information. Nodes can be placed internally, connecting the user to anyone of their choice or as much info as their family can afford. (Information is money is power).

Never forget the threat. Weapons defensive or otherwise would be an essential part of the powerful's survival-kit. Why not carry them where they can't be easily seen and countered. Sure, finger-darts/lasers/knives seem obvious, but why not claws, venomous-bristles, fangs etc..

Built-in "Tricorder" (copyright Paramount Global). Handy for the super-rich to keep track of everything around them for any threats.

Immortality. Perhaps the most exclusive aspiration: With implants, the identity can be recorded. All somato-sensory information, memories, emotional patterns - perhaps even thoughts. In the event of sudden death these can be used to re-pattern the mind of a fresh new body. (Or, in the case of implant destruction, the most recent upload can be used).

Tech-power. The ability to hijack the implants of others - parents of their wayward children, law-enforcement of an arrest target, rivalrous businesses over each-other for market-share. Some would be sanctioned and regulated (eg. parenting, law enforcement), much would be a race of jackware Vs anti-jackware and effectively outside the law.



Oh, I forgot  the ever popular voice implant. Useful for impersonations, Karaoke and amusement.

Change Them
Since we're getting close to the technological singularity, the possibility of mind transfers becomes real.

In the book Altered Carbon by Richard Morgan, people swap bodies constantly, in fact, bodies are referred to as "sleeves"
A poor person is stuck with their one body for life or if really unlucky in life, they can sell it and buy a old body or synthetic android body or even get stuck in a virtual existence.
The ultra rich on the other hand swap bodies all the time. They buy custom made bodies with built in enhancements and are eternally young and healthy. If a body becomes damaged or starts to age, they just buy another one.
Basically, bodies just become a fashion accessory and, if you're rich enough, you change it with the seasons to match current trends.

Peacock tails
Peacock tails were a problem for Darwin (“The sight of a feather in a peacock's tail, whenever I gaze at it, makes me sick!”) — why? Because it was a direct violation of survival of the fittest, as if ever a predator came along, it would clearly be a hindrance to survival.
Later work has suggested this is because, and I'm oversimplifying somewhat, the ability to survive despite those tails is a demonstration that they are otherwise very healthy and thus gets them more mating opportunities. In humans, we see a similar process already, as the rich will spend as much on a mechanical wristwatch as most people spend on buying an apartment, but that mechanical wristwatch will be slightly worse at keeping time than a Casio F-91W costing $20.
So what would the super-rich choose in a world of plenty a few hundred years from now, where anyone can have as much life-extension as they want, where radical full-body surgery is as trivial as long-haul flights today and so they can be changed into real-life furries for a weekend party and returned to normal by Monday?
They will choose to look like they're ill.
They'd cosplay as a 90-year old with the medical tech of 1902, a bent back and a walking stick, and a brass horn to hear with, just to prove they're so rich they don't have to look good like all the plebs around them.
